# Acumatica REST API SalesInvoice

Tags: c#, webforms, acumatica

I'm trying to create Sales Orders and Invoices via Acumatica ERP's REST API.
For some reason I'm getting error only for creation of the Invoices through I'm using almost the same JSON's for both:

Here is my RestService:

```
public class RestService : IDisposable
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;

    private readonly string _acumaticaBaseUrl;

    #region Ctor
    public RestService(string acumaticaBaseUrl, string userName, string password, string company, string branch, string locale)
    {
        _acumaticaBaseUrl = acumaticaBaseUrl;
        _httpClient = new HttpClient(
            new HttpClientHandler
            {
                UseCookies = true,
                CookieContainer = new CookieContainer()
            })
        {
            BaseAddress = new Uri(acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/Default/6.00.001/"),
            DefaultRequestHeaders =
            {
                Accept = {MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue.Parse("text/json") }
            }
        };

        //Log in to Acumatica ERP
        _httpClient.PostAsJsonAsync(
          acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/login", new
          {
              name = userName,
              password = password,
              company = company,
              branch = branch,
              locale = locale
          }).Result
            .EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }



    void IDisposable.Dispose()
    {
        _httpClient.PostAsync(_acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/logout",
          new ByteArrayContent(new byte[0])).Wait();
        _httpClient.Dispose();
    }
    #endregion
    //Data submission
    public string Put(string entityName, string parameters, string entity)
    {
        var res = _httpClient.PutAsync(_acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/Default/6.00.001/" + entityName + "?" + parameters, new StringContent(entity, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result
            .EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        return res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}
```

And here is the Main code:

```
using (RestService service = new RestService(ACUMATICA_INSTANCE_URL, USERNAME,PASSWORD,COMPANY, "", "EN-US"))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Login successful");

    string order = @"{  
        ""OrderNbr"":{ value: ""000204"" },
        ""CustomerID"":{ value: ""TESTCST005""},
        ""Details"": [ 
        {
            ""InventoryID"": { value: ""301CMPST02"" },
            ""Quantity"": { value: 10 }
        }]
    }";
    string invoice = @"{  
        ""ReferenceNbr"":{ value: ""001032"" },
        ""CustomerID"":{ value: ""TESTCST005""},
        ""Details"": [ 
        {
            ""InventoryID"": { value: ""DESIGN"" },
            ""Quantity"": { value: 10 }
        }]
    }";

    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Trying to create the following Order");
        Console.WriteLine(order);
        string updatedOrder = service.Put("SalesOrder", null, order);
        Console.WriteLine("Order created successful");
        Console.WriteLine(updatedOrder);

        Console.WriteLine("Trying to create the following Invoice");
        Console.WriteLine(invoice);
        string updatedInvoice = service.Put("SalesInvoice", null, invoice);
        Console.WriteLine("Invoice created successful");
        Console.WriteLine(updatedInvoice);
    }
    catch(Exception exc)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(exc.Message);
    }
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

I'm not able to find out what is the problem. The response I'm getting is always the following:

> "StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error', Version: 1.1, Content: System.Net.Http.StreamContent, Headers:\r\n{\r\n  X-Handled-By: Acumatica-PX.Export/AuthenticationManagerModule\r\n  Cache-Control: private\r\n  Set-Cookie: Locale=TimeZone=GMTM0500G&Culture=en-US; path=/\r\n  Set-Cookie: UserBranch=5; path=/\r\n  Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5\r\n  X-Powered-By: ASP.NET\r\n  Date: Wed, 02 Aug 2017 13:02:49 GMT\r\n  Content-Length: 36\r\n  Content-Type: text/json; charset=utf-8\r\n}"

I'm able to add the Invoice from Screen with these same values.
Here is the example of using Acumatica ERP REST API to Create a Customer
[Creation of a Record](https://help.acumatica.com/(W(4))/?ScreenId=ShowWiki&pageid=9d966d50-a0a1-4456-a9ff-1cc2159d48d4).

Comment: What is in the content of the response? It should contain error description.

Comment: @SergRogovrsev it has only Internal Server Error

Comment: @SergRogovtsev http://take.ms/sBOEFn

Comment: @SergRogovtsev I have read the content and the message is "{\"message\":\"An error has occurred.\"}"

Comment: What does FirstChanceExceptionLog say?

Comment: @SergRogovtsev FirstChanceException event raised in ConsoleApp19.exe: Response status code does not indicate success: 500 (Internal Server Error).

Comment: @SergRogovtsev If I understand correct this problem is with the specific Screen as I have created new Screen to the same Maintenance of the System and the REST is working correct with mine.

Comment: I'm not talking about your console application first-chance exceptions, I'm interested in Acumatica's first-chance exceptions.

Comment: @SergRogovtsev and how can I get Acumatica's first-chance exception?

Comment: http://asiablog.acumatica.com/2015/11/using-acumatica-first-chance-exception.html

Comment: @SergRogovtsev http://take.ms/vhgwj  but I don't want to bind this Invoice to any Shipment or Sales Order also my Inventory Item is non stock so the Invoice should have been created

Comment: Seems like your desire contradicts with some business requirement found during the development. I suggest you file a Support Case.

Answer (score 0):

I did not have your "PostAsJsonAsync" function so I had to revert to the method used in the documentation provided from Acumatica and use the following :

```
string credentialsAsString = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new
{
    name = userName,
    password = password,
    //company = Properties.Settings.Default.CompanyName,
    //branch = Properties.Settings.Default.Branch
});

var response = _httpClient.PostAsync(acumaticaBaseUrl + "/entity/auth/login", new StringContent(credentialsAsString, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json")).Result;
```

But once i did this the only error I found was a JSON structure error.
You are forgetting to put the value keyword between double quotes.

This :

```
string order = @"{  
    ""OrderNbr"":{ value: ""000204"" },
    ""CustomerID"":{ value: ""TESTCST005""},
    ""Details"": [ 
    {
        ""InventoryID"": { value: ""301CMPST02"" },
        ""Quantity"": { value: 10 }
    }]
}";
```

Should be corrected by this :

```
string order = @"{  
    ""OrderNbr"":{ ""value"": ""000204"" },
    ""CustomerID"":{ ""value"": ""TESTCST005""},
    ""Details"": [ 
    {
        ""InventoryID"": { ""value"": ""301CMPST02"" },
        ""Quantity"": { ""value"": 10 }
    }]
}";
```

Comment: I'm not having any problem with the creation of sales order also PostAsyncAsJson is method from net.formatters. I will add the link to the documentation that I have used a little later

Comment: Your answer is not answering to my question at all. I have not any problem with PostAsyncAsJson also I have not any problem with the JSON for Sales Order

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue and resolved.

Issue is that Customer "TESTCST005" does not exist in the system.
You need to create a new customer :)